# how can i assign float value to char* c[] array

Tags: c++, c

I have string,int,float values and trying to assign those values to char* c[] array like this.

```
char *str = "helloo";
int int = 1000;
short st1[]={32760};
float flt = 2.345; 
char*  c [] = {(char*)int1,(char*)str,(char*)flt,(char*)st1};
```

but for float getting **illegal explicit conversion from 'float' to 'char * '** 
anybody tel me how to assign?

Comment: just for constants or variables too?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? The simple answer is "you can't, since a float isn't a char* and there is no sensible conversion".

Comment: What are you trying to *achieve*? What's your desired result? Don't use words like "assign" loosely, but rather say in plain English what your goals are.

Comment: you cannot assign float to char. ASCII has only 256 characters. if you change int to char directly using cast, int value (less then 255) will change to char value according to ASCII value.

Comment: Actually, ASCII only has 128 characters (0-127), to allow for signed or unsigned bytes.

Comment: in java Object[] is there in which we can assign all kind of values like byte,int,short,float etc so in c i am trying to do same

Comment: Java is a fully object oriented language, and is very different from C++. Pretty much anything can be treated as an object. In C++ built in types (`int`, `float`, etc) are *not* of class type. You would need to create some kind of inheritance hierarchy for all the types you want, inheriting from some shared base, then have an array of pointers to the base type.

Comment: 'you cannot assign float to char' -- which isn't what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: "so in c i am trying to do same" -- Why do you think 'char*' is the "same" as Java's Object? When you put a Java int into an Object[], the int gets "boxed" into an Integer object, a pointer to which is stored into the array. C/C++ casts and char* don't work anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just *cast* those types and expect to get useful results. Casting is a minimal operation which can work to transform data  in certain predefined ways, but it won't (for example) intelligently turn integers into their string representations.

That's why your compiler is complaining.

If you want the string representation of numeric data, you have to convert them differently, with something like:

```
char intStr[30]
sprintf (intStr, "%d", int1);
```

If you're looking to get string representations of them all, you can do something like:

```
char *str = "helloo";
int int1 = 1000;
short st1[]={32760};
float flt = 2.345; 

char mybuff1[50], mybuff2[50], mybuff3[50], mybuff4[50];
sprintf (mybuff1, "%d", int1);
sprintf (mybuff2, "%s", str);
sprintf (mybuff3, "%f", flt);
sprintf (mybuff4, "%d", st1[0]);

char *c [] = {mybuff1, mybuff2, mybuff3, mybuff4);
```

---

And be aware that, although C and C++ have very similar idioms, and are mostly compatible if you stick to a subset, they are *not* the same language and the best way to do something changes dramatically depending on the actual language you're using.

For example, it's rarely necessary to use C-style strings in C++ since that language provides an impressive real string type. Ditto for `malloc/free` as opposed to `new/delete` and many other aspects.

Questions should generally be tagged C or C++, rarely both.

Comment: thanks,can i do reverse means from string is it possible to store float value back??

Comment: The OP wants to do something like storing an int into a Java Object[]. That implies boxing, not conversion to a string.

Comment: Casting is not an operation which “just treats the underlying data as a different form“ and “does not transform the data itself.” For example, the cast `(int) 3.5f` truncates the value and converts it from a floating-point representation to a binary integer representation. The underlying data is (typically) changed from 0x40600000 to 0x00000003.

Answer (score 2):

In C++:

```
#include <string>

std::string arr[] = { std::to_string(1000),
                      "helloo",
                      std::to_string(2.345f),
                      std::to_string(32760)    };
```

You can use `arr[0].c_str()` etc. to get back `char const *`s.

Comment: `std::to_string` is a **C++11** feature, so you need a **C++11** compiler.